# iphone drow shadow on circle

Tags: iphone, uiview, dropshadow

I have a simple circle drawn in my sub classed uiview as below. How do I add a slight drowshadow on the bottom of the circe?

```
 - (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
   {
     CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
     UIGraphicsPushContext(ctx);
     CGContextSetRGBFillColor(ctx, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);  // white color
     CGContextFillEllipseInRect(ctx, CGRectMake(10.0f, 10.0f, 100.0f, 100.0f));  // a white filled circle with a diameter of 100 pixels, centered in (60, 60)
     UIGraphicsPopContext();

     //Now what here?
   }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To follow on slf's answer, you'd replace the code above with:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    UIGraphicsPushContext(ctx);
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(ctx, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);  // white color
    CGContextSetShadow(ctx, CGSizeMake(2.0f, 2.0f), 2.0f);
    CGContextFillEllipseInRect(ctx, CGRectMake(10.0f, 10.0f, 100.0f, 100.0f));  // a white filled circle with a diameter of 100 pixels, centered in (60, 60)
    UIGraphicsPopContext();
}
```

This will create a shadow that is offset by 2 pixels down and to the right of your circle, with a blur of 2 pixels.  You can alter these values to create the effect you want.  CGContextSetShadowWithColor() can also be used with a different color than black, if you want to add a glow effect to this drawing.

Answer (score 1):

See [Quartz2D Shadows](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_shadows/dq_shadows.html) guide.

```
CGContextSetShadowWithColor (myContext, myShadowOffset, 5, myColor);
```

Comment: how do we set the size of the shadow or the opacity?

Comment: @VanDuTran the `5` above is the size, but they call it blur.  The opacity is part of the color.

Comment: Hm.. ok it's pretty weird how they use this.. blur of 4 and 10 is very light, while a value of 6 to 8 is more "opaque". I was setting it to 20 and couldn't see the shadow at all